# Reduce component count for BCD input error detection

Tags: circuit-design, switches, comparator, binary

I made this circuit that reads the input of the DIP switches and detects if the input is an error or not a BCD value. The problem is I have 4 inputs for my circuit.

The LED indicate if the input is correct or wrong; if correct then allow input to pass, if not, output zero.

[image]

Im having trouble implementing this to the breadboard as it requires 2 breadboard just to make this and the expenses might not cater for it.

I am required to only use 74ls ic's

How can I reduce the component count of the overall circuit?

Comment: @winny no, since it is required to make this in breadboard with combinational logic gates and 74ls ics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4Hz9g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you this one's easy to implement for my circuit thanks

Answer (score -1):

An approach I might take would be to take advantage of the existing 7-segment display and avoid the use of the binary LED outputs. It's not difficult to make the 7-segment display produce an **E** error out, instead.

To do this, I'd break up the input into two modules:

- A display module that emulates the 7447 except that it accepts an error indication input which will force the display to show **E** in those cases, regardless of the supplied binary input. It doesn't detect errors. But it accepts an error indication, which overrides the display segments. But it otherwise acts similarly to the 7447. (It also doesn't accept or deal with blanking, though.
- A 4-bit BCD input module that can generate the error indication. The 4-bit input and the error indication is placed at its output.

Let's start with the top-level:

[image]

This just takes in the BCD input, feeds it both to the output as well as the **BCDE** module (see below) and to the modified **7447E** module (also see below.) The ***ERR*** indicator from the **BCDE** module is also passed along to the **7447E** module. The basic ideas here are very easy to understand and read.

Next, the **BCDE** module would be nothing more than the following:

[image]

And finally the **7447E** module would look like this:

[image]

This last **7447E** module always outputs an ***E*** on the display if the ***ERR*** input is **1**. Otherwise, it processes the 4-bit input just like a 7447 would.

This breaks things up into useful sections that can be applied again and again.

Comment: This is not an answer to *"How can I reduce the component count of the overall circuit?"*

Comment: @DaveTweed The comparators are gone. So I disagree.

Comment: @periblepsis i like the idea of having it output an E to indicate an error, but wouldn't it make the circuit need more ic's? Since im using the AND, OR, NOT gates for each input?

Comment: @Noobielectrix It requires just what I show, above. No more, no less. I also like the idea of showing an error **E**, by the way. It's clear.